# What are the options for generating a report in SonarQube v6.3.1

Tags: sonarqube

The Governance plugin is not working with the version. And pdf-report plugin is also not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no option that we are aware of.

You are right that Governance is indeed not compatible with SonarQube 6.3.1 because it's not a LTS (Long Term Supported) version - and Governance is released only for LTS versions of SonarQube.